# Trouble with char and char* in function join()

Tags: c, linux, join, char, valgrind

I'm implementing a function in C with the following signature:

```
char *join(char **strv, char sep);
```

The function receives an array of strings and it returns a string with all the substrings in the array, separated with the character "sep".

My code works, but Valgrind complains:

> ==2526== Command: ./strutil
>
> ==2526==
>
> ==2526== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
>
> ==2526==    at 0x4C2EC78: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
>
> ==2526==    by 0x400CDE: strcat (string3.h:148)
>
> ==2526==    by 0x400CDE: join (strutil.c:90)
>
> ==2526==    by 0x4006EE: main (strutil.c:117)
>
> ==2526==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
>
> ==2526==    at 0x400C30: join (strutil.c:72)
>
> ==2526==
>
> ==2526== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
>
> ==2526==    at 0x4C2EC78: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
>
> ==2526==    by 0x400CDE: strcat (string3.h:148)
>
> ==2526==    by 0x400CDE: join (strutil.c:90)
>
> ==2526==    by 0x400722: main (strutil.c:121)
>
> ==2526==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
>
> ==2526==    at 0x400C30: join (strutil.c:72)
>
> ==2526==
>
> ==2526==
>
> ==2526== HEAP SUMMARY:
>
> ==2526==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==2526==   total heap usage: 15 allocs, 15 frees, 474 bytes allocated
>
> ==2526==
>
> ==2526== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
>
> ==2526==
>
> ==2526== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
>
> ==2526== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

This is how I invoke the function:

```
char *result = join(strv, ';');
```

I figured out I could solve the problem by using double quotes, and changing the function signature to char *join(char **strv, char* sep); but I'm not supposed to change the function signature.

This is the line that's causing me trouble:

```
strcat(string, &sep);
```

"string" is the return value.

Is there a way I can solve the problem without changing the function signature?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*Is there a way I can solve the problem without changing the function signature?*" There definitely is, whether you were able to go this way, we do not know.

Comment: See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The answer is yes, you can dynamically allocate a string within `join` sufficient to hold all of the strings in `strv` plus the number of `sep` required `+1` for the *nul-terminating* character at the end. You return a pointer to your newly allocated string. Otherwise, you must pass a character array of sufficient size as a parameter. (any string declared local to `join` is destroyed when `join` returns).

Comment: I was able to solve the problem using an array with the 'sep' char stored in its first position. Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

No, this problem is unsolvable given that signature, because you cannot iterate through an array in C without knowing its size.

If you changed the signature to include some kind of dimensions, then you could take the approach given by David Rankin in your comments.

Comment: I solved it using an array with the 'sep' char stored in the first position, then concatenating the array to the string returned by the function. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: That isn't a solution to the problem you specified though, since your solution *only* works if the array is constructed artificially in a particular way, which I doubt is what they are after.

Comment: I included the array construction inside the function join itself, then destroyed it within the same function. Why wouldn't it work? Just genuinely wondering.

Comment: @Jime25 but your function is passed an array of unspecified size, right? How do you determine the size of that array? You can't...

Comment: I loop through the array until NULL (the array of strings passed as parameter is null-terminated), and increment a variable "pos" (as well as a variable "length", using strlen(strv[pos]) ). That's what I did to allocate the memory for the string in the first place. Is that wrong?

Comment: Ok. When you say 'NULL terminated', do you mean the last item in the array of strings is a NULL pointer? If that is the case, then that is a crucial piece of information you missed out of your post. Without that information, the problem is unsolvable.

Comment: Yes, the last item is a NULL pointer. Sorry I missed that out, and thank you again